# How do I stabilize soldiers?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

So I've got a critically wounded soldier lying around. My medic has moved into range, but the med-pack icon remains greayed out. However, I can still select the med-pack and target the soldier, and the tooltip tells me to stabilize the target. However, pressing "Ok" does nothing. I've had this exact situation twice, in different missions. Is that a bug?

Comment: Have you already used the medkit the maximum number of times per mission? (1 without the appropriate perks)

Comment: Alternately, if you haven't used the med pack up already, are you *sure* you are pressing the right icon?  There's a separate icon for reviving.

Comment: @peacedog yes that was it, I missed the new icon because that soldier already had a bajillion skills. Make it an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is actually a separate skill for reviving downed members.  It's a different icon than the heal skill (and if your skill bars are anything like mine, it's way on the other end, and it moves around from time to time).  And yes, you do need a medpack charge available for use.

Comment: Also need to actually have a med pack to use.

Comment: Yep, worth adding that.